# CSS only partially rendering when using HTML with Flask?

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I've been using Python and Flask to host a webpage, which renders data from HTML. The Python code runs well, and is able to load the routes/webpages I'm targeting. However, my HTML page only seems to partially apply the Stylesheet.

However, when I render the page, it only seems to render the styling for the Nav Bar (TopNav class).
I've tried a few things, such as using IDs, creating new classes and adding to a div, using code from W3 to prevent typos, and even creating a new test html document with the same stylesheet. However, I still seem to be having the same issue.

What I'd like the stylesheet to do is provide a background color for the button, display it (along with ~20 total buttons) in a grid-like manner, and use a different background image for each button. I also played with the idea of adding the images using in-line styles, but that didn't help either.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='Styles.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="/">Home</a>
  <a href="/standings">Standings</a>
  <a href="/results">Results</a>
  <a class="active" href="/teams">Teams</a>
  <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
</div>
<div class="team-buttons">

    <button  type="button" class="team-button"><a href="/link">Text</a></button>

    <button  type="button" class="team-button" id='Wolves' ><a href="/link">Text</a></button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS

```
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.team-buttons button {
  background-color: #4CAF50; 
  border: 1px solid green; 
  color: white; 
  padding: 10px 24px; 
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50%; 
  display: block;
}

.team-buttons button:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: none; 
}

.team-buttons button:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}


.team-button {
  background-color: #ef4242;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.team-button a {
  float: left;
  color: #070000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#wolves{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  background-image: url('https://images.racingpost.com/football/teambadges/2848.png');
    cursor:pointer;
    border:none;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Apologies if I've missed something obvious, but I've been looking through this for a few hours now and still not found what the issue might be. Insight into this would be helpful.

Comment: maybe first use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox to check what file it loads - maybe it loads some old file. You can also use `DevTools` to see what values it assigned. Or see if there was no error in CSS file and it can't understand some of your CSS rules.

Comment: you could also remove all rules which don't work and put them one by one and check if there is no conflict between rules - maybe one rule add something but other rule remove it. For example you set `background-color` in `.team-buttons button` but later you change it in `.team-button`

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this.

I think the issue I was running into was that the webpage was pulling data from the cache. As the .topnav had been added earlier, that was loaded into the style sheet, however, the newer classes weren't being added.
Found this by right-clicking and going to View Page Source.

Simple fix for this would be clearing cache, or Ctrl + Shift + R (to force a reload)